# Node http module

Tags: node.js

I am currently stumped with a problem, where the http.request() just fails/skips to make a request to a given url. I have the following setup

```
async.waterfall([
    firstFunc,
    secondFunc,
    thirdFunc
], function last(err, result){});
```

The **thirdFunc** is where i am making a request and it looks like the following

```
function thirdFunc(payload, callback){
    var responseFromCS = getData(payload);
    callback(null, responseFromCS);

}
```

The **getData** function looks like the following

```
function getData(obj){
    var curlttogetdata = csConstants.BasePath + csConstants.account_num;
    var accountNum = obj.customer.accountnum;
    var resData = null;
    curlttogetdata = curlttogetdata.replace('${accntNum}', accountNum);

    var getData = {
        hostname: csURLHost,
        path: curlttogetdata,
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-consumer-id': csConstants.ConsumerIDHeader,
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    };
    var req = http.request(getData, function (res){
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function getData(chunk){
            body += chunk
        });

        res.on('end', function parseData(){
            try {
                resData = JSON.parse(body);
            }catch(err){
                resData = false;
            }
        });

    });

    req.on('error', function csResponseError(err){
        resData = false;
    });

    req.end();
    return resData;
}
```

Now upon debugging, once the debugger reaches http.request(...) it fails to step into callback or make the request and then steps right into req.end(). There is no error returned back. I have looked at my parameters in the **getData** object a number of times and everything looks fine. Even tested this with a curl and gives back the expected response.

Comment: Which library are you using for `http`?

Comment: the core node 'http' module, i think i have an answer and know why i am facing this issue. I will post my answer soon

Answer (score 1):

one thing I see immediately is that you are returning resData as if it was a synchronous execution, meaning the httpRequest comes back after resData gets returned from your getData function, which will be null at that point

basically
when your program is executing
it does this
1 -makes http request, 
2 -returns resData which is null (because the function executes until the end without stopping)
3 -the http request comes back and now resData has value but your function has already returned

what you need to do is pass a callback function
instead of

```
var responseFromCS = getData(payload);
you do getData(payload, function(responseFromCS){
//..... do something with the returned data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i believe i know the reasoning behind this. The 'http' node module is an async operation and the function **getData** that handles this, which is wrapped under **thirdFunc** in the async operation. I believe this operation gets executed before **getData** can respond.

So i moved the http.request() into **thirdFunc** and it works as expected.